# Scroll to bindable element in stacklayout in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using scrollview and stacklayout to display comments on my xaml page:
https://pastebin.com/MUTdkaSj
In OnAppearing method i am try to find element in stacklayout and scroll to it:

```
public partial class TicketPage : ContentPage
    {
        public Ticket Ticket { get; private set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Comment> Comments { get; private set; }

        private string _commentId;

        public TicketPage(Ticket ticket) : base()
        {
            Ticket = ticket;
            Comments = new ObservableCollection<Comment>(Ticket.comments);
            BindingContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public TicketPage(Ticket ticket, string commentId) : this(ticket)
        {
            _commentId = commentId;
        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_commentId))
                return;

            int commentIndex = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < Comments.Count; i++)
            {
                if (Comments[i]._id == _commentId)
                {
                    commentIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (commentIndex == -1)
                return;

            Element element = CommentsList.Children[commentIndex];
            await Scroll.ScrollToAsync(element, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
        }
       //...
}
```

But it's doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does "doesn't work" mean?  Is your code finding the correct element?  Is the `ScrollToAsync` not working?

Comment: My code find correct element but ScrollToAsync not working

Comment: Does OnAppearing run on a background thread? If so, you may need to wrap the actual ScrolltoAsync call in Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread

Comment: I tried to start it in the main thread and it didn't work. But if we add await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1000); before scroll to async it will work

Comment: Does this mean you have solved the problem? If so, please add "Your Answer" below, showing the code snippet that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your commentIndex is staying -1. You can use Linq for this.

Let me give you an example how you could do this.
To get an element, instead of finding index of that class in list just find the class in the list and then for element, use the Linq and check for the BindingContext.

```
Comment bdContext = Comments.First(x => x._id == _commentId);
Element element = MainLayout.Children.First(x => x.BindingContext == bdContext);
if (element != null)
{
    await Scroll.ScrollToAsync(element, ScrollToPosition.Start, true);
}
```

This similar case worked for me. And just a suggestion, if you don't have anything below the item you want to scroll to then don't use "ScrollToPosition.Start" instead use "ScrollToPosition.MakeVisible".